# Want to get CSS Text Wrap working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

The following code renders great in FF3 but doesn't work in IE7. Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

```
<div style="padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:5px;width:650px;background:blue">
    <div style="height:50px;float:left;display:inline;width:500px;background:gray">http://www.brainsolis.com/2008/10/twitter-tools-for-comunity-and-love-for-...</div>
    <div style="width:100%;text-align:right;float-right;background:yellow">saaal is saaa twittertool ds ds dsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd sdf dsf sdf sdf sdf sd ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to *float* an element, and *display:inline* at the same time. Additionally, you do not need to set *width:100%* for DIV elements. They will naturally take up all available horizontal space.

The following CSS should achieve what you are attempting.

```
div.container {

}
  div.floated {
    width:50px;
    float:left;
  }
  div.textbody {
    /* styles */
  }
  br.clear {
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    line-height:0;
  }

<div class="container">
  <div class="floated">
    <p>This is floated</p>
  </div>
  <div class="textbody">
    <p>...text body...</p>
  </div>
  <br class="clear" />
</div>
```

For more information on CSS, check [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/default.asp), or watch the [CSS Videos at SampsonVideos](http://www.sampsonvideos.com/).

Comment: Actually, setting display: inline to any element that is floated will help IE6 render it correctly.

Comment: Then it's best to set it in an IE6-specific stylesheet via conditional comments.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked your sample but this took care of IE wrapping problems for me:

```
div
{
  word-wrap: break-word;  /* for IE, force it to wrap text and keep it inside the div */
}
```

Comment: This does not work; not sure why you posted this answer.  There is no standard that follows this and neither IE6 nor IE7 use this.

Comment: @Kevin: This page seems to suggest that this works in IE 5.5-7 : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap#AutoCompatibilityTable

Answer (score 1):

the css word-wrap directive is working for me

tried in ie6, 7, 8 and chrome (as usual, firefox wrap my text correctly even without it)

seems to be an IE invention but also css3 compatible (http://www.css3.com/css-word-wrap/)