# Text not wrapping in div with a width within IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

In IE7 the text in a div with a width that is narrower than the text will not wrap to two lines. It works on other browsers better than IE7.

```
<div class="office-header-info">
<div class="local-office">District of Columbia</div>
</div>
```

```css
.office-header-info {
  float: left;
}

.local-office {
  color: #893f22;
  width: 165px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 17px;
  white-space: normal;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
```

In IE7 District of Columbia stays on one line when in other browsers it is

> District of 
> Columbia

Which is what it should be, so IE7 isn't correct with one line like District of Columbia. If I add overflow:hidden it gets cut off.

Anything about this that explains why the text will not wrap to two lines in IE7?

Comment: Try floating `.local-office` too.

Comment: This has some helpful tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458922/want-to-get-css-text-wrap-working-in-ie7

Comment: Did you try out Overflow Auto?

Comment: just tried it in latest Chrome, IE6, IE7: identical results in all three browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/EjaB6/

Answer (score 0):

```
white-space: pre; /* CSS 2.0 */
white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS 2.1 */
white-space: pre-line; /* CSS 3.0 */
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
white-space: -hp-pre-wrap; /* HP Printers */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5+ */
```

Give that a go.

Comment: None of the suggestions worked, but the jsfiddle.net link gave me an idea to keep adding divs and styles until it does break.

Comment: He labeled this as an issue with IE7 yet you're giving him a solution which covers Opera, Mozilla, and HP printers?

Comment: @animuson yes, I am.  Just in case he wants more control over his div and how it's wrapping.